# Metatag Database updates need to be ran

Tags: 7, meta-tags

When im trying to add new node it gives me Error : The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

When I checked in Reports. I got this.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'revision_id' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM {metatag} WHERE
>   (entity_type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (entity_id =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (revision_id =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND (language =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_3) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => node [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 133 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 133 [:db_condition_placeholder_3] =>
>   und ) in metatag_metatags_save() (line 559 of
>   /home/public_html/sites/all/modules/metatag/metatag.module).

Im using
Drupal 7.31
Metatag 7.x-1.0-rc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a local setup of drupal with meta tags module installed.

Now check for its table structure, if any of the table or column is missing add it manually. Because it can be issue occured you enabled the module.

Other soluion can be disable **metatag** module then uninstall it and then re-enable it. It might fix issue for you.
It is just the issue of missing table and column field.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks.. I have added revision_id column manually. It Works for me

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the two most commonly missed fields are 'revision_id' and 'language'.

It's possible the module had been installed before but improperly removed, or, if the site is old enough, it's possible that the original "Metatags" module was previously added (which will thoroughly confuse Metatag).

As Raj10 suggested, the best approach to take is to check to see what columns are missing in the database and fix it as appropriate.

Disclaimer: I'm the module's maintainer.